# unable to install quadprog package on R Version 2.13.0 on mac

Tags: r

I am unable to install quadprog package on R Version 2.13.0 on mac

install.packages("quadprog", repos="http://R-Forge.R-project.org")

Warning message:
In getDependencies(pkgs, dependencies, available, lib) :
  package ‘quadprog’ is not available (for R version 2.13.0)

Regards,
Jasdeep Mandia

Answer (score 2):

Simply enough, quadprog isn't hosted on r-forge.  Why are you trying to use r-forge instead of CRAN?

Comment: thx.if i remove R-forge also, installation doest take place. if I use command install.packages("quadprog") .it gives following error :trying URL 'http://cran.mirrors.hoobly.com/bin/macosx/leopard/contrib/2.13/quadprog_1.5-4.tgz'
Error in download.file(url, destfile, method, mode = "wb", ...) : 
cannot open URL 'http://cran.mirrors.hoobly.com/bin/macosx/leopard/contrib/2.13/quadprog_1.5-4.tgz'
In addition: Warning message:
In download.file(url, destfile, method, mode = "wb", ...) :
cannot open: HTTP status was '0 (null)'
Warning in download.packages(pkgs, destdir = tmpd, available = available,:

Comment: Looks like an issue with your internet connection.  I don't have an issue downloading the package via the [link](http://cran.mirrors.hoobly.com/bin/macosx/leopard/contrib/2.13/quadprog_1.5-4.tgz) you posted.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you are thinking of `Rquadprog`? It is hosted on r-forge. On a Mac you will need to use the type="source" argument to install.packages for anything on r-forge, and you may need to install Xcode if the package is not just pure R code.